# zebra 3842 - slow label printing with .net

Tags: .net, performance, printing, label

I'm facing with problem that the zebra 3842 label printer works slow.

I use standard .net printing framework. (System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument)
After I call PrintDocument's Print() function, printer waits for a few seconds and print first label. then it waits a sec again and pull back the label and prints. the process goes like that.

You can see the situation from the following video: (single print call, with 3 pages)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DeIoO6qT0kE

I tried to print 3 page with the Microsoft Word application. (and same situation exists too)
However, If I use Zebra's software to print labels, it works normally without delays.

I also installed most recent drivers.

I'm new to the label printing so I ask help from the experienced people.
What may be the problem? What should I check first?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, the class that you are using (PrintDocument) doesn't understand the printer's native language (EPL - I think!).  Even though your label design is simple, PrintDocument can't generate EPL, so it simply creates a image the size of your entire label and sends the image down to the Zebra printer driver.  Since the driver is simply being handed an image, it doesn't 'know' that you are really just printing text and a box or two.  Instead, it sends the entire label down to the printer for printing.  So instead of just sending some light-weight EPL text commands, data representing the entire label area as an image is now being sent down.  This means you are sending kilobytes of data instead of bytes of data.  Furthermore, the driver is having to work to convert the image data into a large EPL graphic command.

I see one obvious alternative, depending on what connection you are using.  It requires that you read a little bit of the EPL manual and put together a label design that works for you.  You can see a sample EPL label here: https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/eltron/common/epl2_samp.htm, and the EPL manual here: https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/eltron/epl2/EPL2_Prog.pdf.

**If using USB:**

Use RawPrinterHelper to send pure EPL commands to the printer through the driver:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091

```
string printerName = "Your_Printer_Driver_Name";
string eplCommand = "N\r\nA50,0,0,1,1,1,N,\"Example 1\"\r\nP1\r\n";
RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(printerName , eplCommand );
```

**If you are using TCP (Ethernet):**

Your job is even simpler.  You don't even need the driver.  Just send the EPL down to the printer over a TCP Connection:

```
string eplString = "N\r\nA50,0,0,1,1,1,N,\"Example 1\"\r\nP1\r\n";

// Open connection
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
client.Connect(ipAddress, port);

// Write EPL String to connection
System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
writer.Write(eplString );
writer.Flush();

// Close Connection
writer.Close();
client.Close();
```

Comment: Hi jason, thanks for your answer. Actually I tried using EPL commands too. (I use RawPrinterHelper class too) Generally, the printer starts the job much sooner if we send EPL rather than using PrintDocument. Interestingly, if I send "P2,1" command to print 2 copy of the label, it prints out without delays. However, if I try to print 2 different labels using "N ... P1 ... N ... P1" command, it waits 2-3 seconds after every label as in the video.  Here is the interesting part: if I send really short EPL command for the label (such as printing only 1 text), it doesn't sleep between labels.

Comment: ..And this situation doesnt change if I use "Direct communication with printer" which is in "Zebra Setup Utilities".